# Is it possible to use an xsl function to set the value of an xml element's attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-attribute

Good Day!

So I've been looking around to for a solution to a problem I have in an integration project with SAP Business One Integration framework.

The long and short of it is that I need to pass the value of an xsl function to serve as the value for an xml element's attribute.

As such:(Or rather, this is what I'm trying to achieve)

```
<Party role=<xsl:value-of select="$msg/BOM/BO/BPAddresses/row/AddressType"/>>
    <PartyIDs>
      blahblah
```

I was wondering. Is it possible to maybe pass a variable to the attribute instead?
Kinda new to xslt and the lot..so any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here. This is the syntax you looking for

```
<Party role="{$msg/BOM/BO/BPAddresses/row/AddressType}">
    <PartyIDs>
       blahblah
```

The curly braces indicates an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literalally.

Note that you can also use the **xsl:attribute** command

```
<Party>
    <xsl:attribute name="role">
        <xsl:value-of select="$msg/BOM/BO/BPAddresses/row/AddressType"/>
    <xsl:attribute>
    <PartyIDs>
       blahblah
```

But as you can see this is a bit more verbose, and Attribute Value Templates are usually the way to go.